# Trimmed video using BLOB URL not giving proper video It is giving video with infinite duration

Tags: angular13

I am using canvas, MediaRecorder, BLOB for create and trim new video from given existing video file ( with mp4/webm and other video extentions ) in Angular 14

For trimming full length video I am use loadmetadata in ngAfterViewInit and giving te framerate 30. After uploading video when we start trimming ts has function startTrimming calls and there are we are creating and starting mediarecorder.

Once our given length is played on video tag then ngAfterViewInit stop the mediaRecorder and call its event listener 'dataavailable' and it creates new Blob of every event.data with type of 'video/webm'. Created blob create the URL using createObjectUrl.

Here created file doesn't load vidoe properly it gives wrong length infinite.

Here is my typescript function which I am using for video trimming :

```
  @ViewChild('videoElement', { static: true })
  videoElement!: ElementRef | any;
  @ViewChild('canvasElement', { static: true })
  canvasElement!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('videoElement1', { static: true })
  videoElement1!: ElementRef | any;

  trim(){
    this.videoElement.nativeElement.currentTime = this.startTime;
    this.videoElement.nativeElement.play();
    this.startTrimming();
  }

  startTrimming() {
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.canvasElement.nativeElement.captureStream(), { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=h264' });
    this.mediaRecorder.start();
  }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.videoElement.nativeElement.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
      this.canvasElement.nativeElement.width = this.videoElement.nativeElement.videoWidth;
      this.canvasElement.nativeElement.height = this.videoElement.nativeElement.videoHeight;
      const ctx = this.canvasElement.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
      const framesPerSecond = 30;
      const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        ctx.drawImage(this.videoElement.nativeElement, 0, 0);
        if (this.videoElement.nativeElement.currentTime >= this.endTime) {
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          this.mediaRecorder.stop();
          this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (event) => {
            const blob:any = new Blob([event.data], { type: 'video/webm' });
            this.videoElement1.nativeElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            // Here I didn't get proper duration but video is playing
          });
        }
      }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);
    });
  }
```

Here is my HTML code for that :

```
<!-- Original video loads in below video tag and we are processing video trimming using below canvas -->
<video #videoElement controls crossOrigin="anonymous" class="w-100"></video>
<canvas #canvasElement style="display: none;"></canvas>

<!-- Below video tag plays trimmed video as per my code -->
<video #videoElement1 controls crossOrigin="anonymous" class="w-100" id="newVid"></video>
```

Here is the screen shot of my duration issue

[I got this video length in video tag and file after trimming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4fjb.png)

[I want video file with duration like in given image in video tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwfyA.png)

[I got this video length in video tag and file after trimming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4fjb.png)

[I want video file with duration like in given image in video tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwfyA.png)